# Cmake compilation adding .cpp vs only including header

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm currently trying to reorganize a library with clean sub folders and small CmakeLists.txt.

If I have a file that includes all the headers from a folder called "foo.h" and add this as only source to a library, then another project using the library throws undefined reference errors. Is there any way this is possible?

Example (failing):

```
cuda_add_library(foo foo.h)

cuda_add_executable(foo_test test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo_test
                          foo)
```

test.cpp:(.text+0x25be): undefined reference to `Graph::Graph()'

foo.h only contains '#include "Graph.h"'

Example (working):

```
cuda_add_library(foo foo.h Graph.cpp)

cuda_add_executable(foo_test test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo_test
                          foo)
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm also open to other ways to cleanly organize the cmake files so that I only have to edit the "foo.h" file whenever I add a new file. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you compiling `Graph.cpp` in some other target?  (If not, how do you expect those symbols to exist?)

Comment: As @ox5453 stated, this seems like you are not compiling Graph.CPP.

Comment: That's true, I'm not adding Graph.cpp to any other target. I've set up a minimal example doing the same without add the cpp file (https://github.com/mimre25/lib-test). I'm somewhat confused of what to add/what not to add.

Comment: My minimal example has the constructor in the header file, that's why it compiles fine. Is there a clean way to add all the .cpp files (other than blobs?) or do I have to add them manually?